# EMF ISO20022 Repository - Message Definitions link to Data Dictionary

Tags: eclipse-plugin, iso, ecore

I have successfully created the Eclipse Plugin from the downloaded ISO20022 ecore implementation metamodel as described: https://www.iso20022.org/iso20022-repository/e-repository

Under the Repository I can see the Data Dictionary and Business Process Catalogue.
I can view and modify the Data Dictionary Message Components.
However when I view the Message Definitions (under Business Process Catalogue) - I can't see how their definitions relate to the Message Components - I would expect the Toplevel Message / Body to link to the Data Dictionary.
(That is the whole point after all: https://www.iso20022.org/understanding-data-dictionary)
Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I've found a workaround: Message Components which happen to be top-level nodes in a Message seem to have the property "Message Building Block" set to the messages they are used in - e.g. Header70 is used in a bunch of the ATICA messages. I did notice however that while I can modify add Message Component properties - I cannot delete properties (even ones I've just added) - I get UnsupportedOperationException - I assume that 
 is deliberate to not allow deletion?